# Construct "Modal Coordinates Time History" from transfer function and test accel-time data

Tags: acceleration, frequency-response, eigenvalue-analysis

I have a query regarding the calculation of the so called “Modal Participation Factor time signal” from a combination of

a) transfer functions (amplitude and phase for each eigenmode) obtained from "unit" accel loading in an FEM model

and

b) real accel-time test data.

I would like to somehow combine the above 2 to obtain the so called "modal participation factor time history".

Can some-one point me in the right direction?
Best Regards

Comment: Is this earthquake/structural dynamics related perchance?

Comment: Engine/structural dynamics

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will be doing this in a software, matlab or Abaqus for example, it’s not particularly easy thing to do with your given info, but. Perhaps this example method will help

1. [Abaqus](https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAEBMKRefMap/simabmk-c-rodlindynamic.htm)
2. Infos at [csiamerica](https://wiki.csiamerica.com/display/kb/Time-history+analysis)
3. [Matlab function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30866-modal-time-history-analysis-of-structures)

I am unsure how directly your data types will fit, but these are some links to get you started

Comment: I suspect i will have to use matlab. I dont see any reference to abaqus in the link.

Comment: The first paragraph clearly states and talks about abaqus

Comment: @user9106985 see update

Comment: Many thanks... I will look at the matlab function.